# Create a dynamic url expression with jasascript or angularjs for google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to create a static image using google maps API and angularJS or JS.

The dynamic version is very simple, I did something like this:

```
<map center="50.575, 52.33" zoom="13" street-view-control="false" map-type-control="false">
    <marker position="{{site.geo}}" title="{{site.name}}" label="{{indexToLetters($index)}}" on-click="showInfoWindow(event, site.geo, site.name)" ng-repeat="site in sites"></marker>
</map>
```

Combining ng-repeat with the marker element creates a map with all the markers. However, I want to export it to PDF, and I can't do it with dynamic map, so I must use static image like so:

```
<img width="750" height="250" ng-src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=50.575, 52.33&zoom=12&size=750x250&sensor=false&markers=HOW-TO-REPEAT-SITE.GEO????>
```

I'm not sure how I can repeat the markers in the image url

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct the image URL in your controller, and then do something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.imgurl = constructImageUrl();
});

function constructImageUrl(){
    var urlbase = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Williamsburg,Brooklyn,NY&zoom=13&size=400x400&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S";

    var markers = ["11211","11206","11222"];
 
    var imgurl = urlbase;
    for(var i in markers){
        imgurl += "%7C" + markers[i];
    }
    
    return imgurl;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <img ng-src="{{imgurl}}" />
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And for anyone else who stumbles across this, here is Google's static map API guide: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro